# Object Storage - Error when reading text file

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, object-storage

When trying to read the content of a text file I received the error message "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openstack4j.openstack.common.DLPayloadEntity incompatible with java.io.File".

How can I read the text file without writing it into a new file?

I tried to convert the file directly into String by using Apache Commons/ IO library's 'readFiletoString()' method:

```
public String test() {
    ObjectStorageDAO os;
    List<String> containers = null;
    String str = null;
    try {
        os = new ObjectStorageDAO(auth_url, userId, password, project, domainName);
        // List the containers
        containers = os.containers();
        SwiftObject so = os.getObject("MyContainer", "message.txt");
        File file = (File) so.download();
        str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        str = e.toString();
    }
    return str;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you're getting class cast exception because you try to cast an Object of one data type (i.e. DLPayloadEntity) to another (i.e. File).

```
    SwiftObject so = os.getObject("MyContainer", "message.txt");
    DLPayloadEntity payload = so.download();
```

With "payload" object, you can retrieve the response following ways;

- getHttpResponse()
- getInputStream()
- writeToFile(File file)

You can do the following to retrieve the text;

```
InputStream stream = payload.getInputStream();
```

"stream" object allows you to read bytes.

Comment: Reading the file as InputStream and converting it to String resolved the issue. 

I changed the try-block to 

try {os = new DictionaryDAO(auth_url, userId, password, project, domainName);
   // List the containers
   containers = os.containers();
   SwiftObject so = os.getObject("SpellChecking", "english.dic");
   DLPayload file = so.download();
   str = getStringFromInputStream(file.getInputStream());
   
   
  } 

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/